# solving for square root with four variables in Mathematica, no response with code

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have tried unsuccessfully to obtain an expression for x with the following
code in Mathematica, where I have 4 variables, x, r, a and b. Any suggestions?

```
Select[x, #1 \[Element] Reals &]
roots = x /.
Solve[
Sqrt[29991348849*x^2 - 13958305552*x + 992000000 - r + a - b] == 0,
x]
result1 = Select[roots, Im@# == 0 &]
```

Comment: What is this? This isn't matlab code

Comment: This is Mathematica code, and it functions correctly.  The reason your `result1` is empty is because your code does not define `{r,a,b}`; therefore, `roots` is a function of `{r,a,b}` and *could* have an imaginary component, so the `Select` returns nothing.

Comment: by inspection of the `Solve` result you can readily show you have two real roots if  `(r + b - a) >= -18957155412540506176/29991348849~~-6 10^8` .. and no real roots otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify @TroyHaskin's comment, the `Re` and `Im` functions will provide the real and imaginary components of a `Complex` number. As your symbols `a` and `b` have no definition the roots found by `Solve` cannot be `Complex`

It should also be noted that `Complex` cannot have a zero imaginary component:

```
Head[Complex[2,0]]
(*Integer*)
```

This expression has real and complex roots:

roots = x /. Solve[(x^4 - 1) (x^4 - 4) == 0, x];
   (*{-1, -I, I, 1, -Sqrt[2], -I Sqrt[2], I Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}*)

The `Complex` roots can be found using `FreeQ` and `!`:

```
Select[roots, !FreeQ[#, _Complex] &]
(*{-I, I, -I Sqrt[2], I Sqrt[2]}*)
```